# Custom popup using bootstrap modal in Kendo scheduler

Tags: kendo-ui, bootstrap-modal, kendo-scheduler

I tried to custom popup by using bootstrap modal for Kendo Scheduler. But my problem is i cant get the day and time for double click the cell.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Share the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

To get the exact star/end time of the clicked slot you can simply pass the clicked element to the [`slotByElement`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-slotByElement) method of the Scheduler. Demo is available in the provided link.